# C Programming: Explanation of why the pointer is not giving the expected value

Tags: c, pointers

I am very new to pointers in C and I am having trouble making sense of this error or a pointer not accessing the memory to store an actual value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a;
    int *pA = &a;

    a = 9;

    *pA = 4;

    int *pA2 = &a;

    printf("pA = %p, *pA = %d, *pA2 = %d\n", *pA, *pA2);
}
```

In (virtual) reality, shouldn't `*pA2* spit out *4* as well? Instead it is giving what looks like a number associated with memory address.

Thanks,

Comment: You have three format specifiers but only two values, are you missing one maybe?

Comment: If your compiler doesn't give you a warning about this, you should enable more warnings. You might try, on GCC or Clang, `std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wconversion`. That will tell you if your `print()` format string does not match the types of the arguments.

Comment: @Davislor Excellent suggestion. I have added this to my answer and credited you. I also like `-Werror`, so you can't be tempted to ignore any warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You have left off an argument to `printf()`. Consider the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   int a;
   int* pA= &a;

   a = 9;

   *pA = 4;

   int* pA2 = &a;

   printf("pA=%p, *pA=%d, *pA2=%d\n", (void*) pA, *pA, *pA2);
}
```

It outputs a memory address, `4`, and `4`  again. [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##TY7BCoMwEETv@YrFYlHRgtJLsRb8il56CUm0gTQJMZVC6a833aiHXnbnzQzLsmpkLISd1Ew9uYDz5Lk0h/uFEKk9PKjUWQ5vAgCRabupwvYd7CNGg0IHp01jgnTcaK028Fe2Ds0hS/BCasvY71K@7AbFTSclZLORvMjB9ou/hnlLPiF82aDoOIUKH@1YXYfqSpXCKV7eUdxWcKq9ZCiZ0bNwkzQ65s4Z9wM)

For each `%` to be substituted, you must pass an extra argument to `printf()`.
When you leave out an argument, the function will try to grab an argument anyway – this leads to **undefined behaviour**. In your case it managed to take a number (presumably from the stack). It could also crash the program – since the behaviour is undefined, there is no way to consistently predict it.

Also note that I have **cast** your pointer to a `void*` for the output – the `%p` format specifier requires it. Other pointers will work most of the time, but are not guaranteed to. Read more about `printf()` [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/printf.html).

To help you detect similar and other problems in the future, turn on compiler warnings. In the beginning, these may seem overwhelming, but they are really helpful. See your code compiled with the compiler flags suggested by [@Davislor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4474419/davislor)'s comment [here](https://tio.run/##TY7BCsIwDIbvfYoymWyyCRMvMif4FF68lLSbhdqWtoogvro126qYQ/L/X/5AoB4AYlxIDerGBd37wKVZXw6ESB3olUldlPRJKNYIWPuTK3ukHV0imRBDs0t6Xm2TS@HNf9o6pH2RTcHcVukk59U3mvOzziY3o7Ilrxjf0Cs2@Fjjnx00TaxPTCns4hEcw2kFZzpIQAlG34Xz0uhx75xxHw).

I have added `-Werror` to these. It forces you to actually deal with the warnings since the compiler won't generate an executable as long as your code generates warnings.

I have also added the same flags to the first link in my answer so you can see it does not generate any warnings.